# How to mock functions returning a sealed class in Mockk?

Tags: kotlin, junit, junit5, mockk, sealed-class

When stubbing a function returning a sealed class with **Mockk** as following

File `BoeTest.kt`

```
package nl.dstibbe.example

import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

sealed class MySeal
data class MyOtherSeal(val value:String) : MySeal()

class MyClass{
    fun someMethod(b: String): MySeal {
        return MyOtherSeal("hooray")
    }
}

class SealTest {
    val mockedClass:MyClass = mockk()

    @Test
    fun `test me`() {
        every { mockedClass.someMethod(any()) } returns MyOtherSeal("something else")   //Fails
    }
}
```

will cause **Mockk** to crash with the stacktrace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the class NestHost, NestMembers, Record, or PermittedSubclasses attribute

    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:169)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.JvmInlineInstrumentation.retransform(JvmInlineInstrumentation.kt:28)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation$doCancel$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:38)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation$doCancel$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:32)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.ClassTransformationSpecMap.applyTransformation(ClassTransformationSpecMap.kt:41)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation.doCancel(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:32)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation.access$doCancel(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:6)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation$execute$1$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:17)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation$execute$1$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:17)
    at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumentation.execute(RetransformInlineInstrumentation.kt:23)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.inline(ProxyMaker.kt:88)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.newProxy$default(AbstractMockFactory.kt:24)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.temporaryMock(AbstractMockFactory.kt:127)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState$call$temporaryMock$1.invoke(RecordingState.kt:69)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmAnyValueGenerator$anyValue$2.invoke(JvmAnyValueGenerator.kt:35)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AnyValueGenerator.anyValue(AnyValueGenerator.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmAnyValueGenerator.anyValue(JvmAnyValueGenerator.kt:31)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.call(RecordingState.kt:75)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:271)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:24)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:21)
    at nl.dstibbe.example.MyClass.someMethod(BoeTest.kt:20)
    at nl.dstibbe.example.BoeTest$test me$1.invoke(BoeTest.kt:12)
    at nl.dstibbe.example.BoeTest$test me$1.invoke(BoeTest.kt:12)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$record$block$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:25)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$enhanceWithRethrow$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:78)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.JvmAutoHinter.autoHint(JvmAutoHinter.kt:23)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:40)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:94)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:143)
    at nl.dstibbe.example.BoeTest.test me(BoeTest.kt:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I must be doing something wrong since Mockk was created for Kotlin and sealed classes are hardly a new thing.
How does one mock a function returning a sealed class in Mockk properly?

Corresponding github issue: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/1041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause and solution: mockk depends on byte-buddy 1.12.20 , certain dependencies however (e.g. mockito-kotlin ) provide a different version of byte-buddy (in my case 1.10.22) . Excluding the other versions and forcing 1.12.20 fixed my issues.

Answer (score 2):

(I get a different stack trace but am using Kotlin 1.8.10 and Mockk 1.12.4 but still able to reproduce the issue.)

I think this case is on the edge of sealed classes/interfaces and a recent tightening of the rules.  We were unwittingly relying on a defect in Kotlin 1.7 where mocks could be created on sealed interfaces (or more specifically like you, subclasses of the sealed item).  This loophole is closed in 1.8.10.

You probably already know that if you change `MyClass.someMethod` to return `MyOtherSeal` then the problem goes away.  So it's all down to the fact that mockk attempts to create a mock instance of `MySeal` which it cannot do.  This does seem strange - why does it need to do this when your `every/returns` does not pass another `mockk()` but a genuine concrete valid object?  Perhaps this is a shortcoming Mockk could address.

So you are not doing anything wrong, you've hit upon the Kotlin 1.8 restriction that Mockk might be able to workaround...

Anyway, I have a workaround.  Ugly, but it might suit your purposes.

Using [this exception for indirect subclasses of sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#location-of-direct-subclasses) you could create an intermediary class that is open, which allows mockk to do its thing:

```
sealed class MySeal
open class Unsealed : MySeal()
data class MyOtherSeal(val value:String) : Unsealed()

class MyClass{
    fun someMethod(b: String): Unsealed {
        return MyOtherSeal("hooray")
    }
}
```

Comment: Awarded the bounty to you. The workaround is not an option for me however.